# Why is my class using the wrong operator()?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Consider the following class `Foo` which provides 2 operators `()`, one for reading and another one for writing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(const std::vector<T> &values) { vals = values; }
  const T &operator()(const int i, const int j) const {
    std::cout << "Read" << std::endl;
    return vals[i];
  }
  T &operator()(const int i, const int j) {
    std::cout << "Write" << std::endl;
    return vals[i];
  } 

 private:
  std::vector<T> vals;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<int> values(100, 1);

  Foo<int> f{values};
  f(1,1) = 42; //here it writes:OK
  std::cout << f(1,1) << std::endl; //why is again the "read" version called?
  return 0;
}
```

I am not able to understand why only the "write" version is called in my code.

Comment: The write version doesn't require any conversion so it's the best match

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I am not able to see what you mean @TedLyngmo

Comment: `f` is non-`const` so no conversion to make `this` a `const Foo<int>*` is needed for the write version. Does it really matter btw?

Comment: But then how can I write the "read" version in this case? I'd like of course that `std::cout << f(1,1) << std::endl;` calls the read one @TedLyngmo

Comment: You can make `f` `const` and then it can _only_ use the read version - or cast: `std::cout << const_cast<const Foo<int>&>(f)(1, 1) << '\n'`

Comment: Look at the syntax and what you wrote; ignore what you intended. One line has the (sub-)expression `f(1,1)`, and another has the (sub-)expression `f(1,1)`. Why should the compiler treat these identical expressions differently?

Comment: Small side note don't use `int` for indexing into containers, use `std::size_t`

Comment: @PepijnKramer Why? If you're sure that the container cannot contain more than `INT_MAX` elements. The index is an arithmetic value, so unsigned integers should be avoided as far as possible, and `int` is the most natural integer type.

Comment: @JamesKanze • because we've been conditioned to support the 0.01% use case, and not the 99.99% use cases.

Comment: @JamesKanze consistency with all C++ containers. Also an int can become negative something that will never be true for sizes.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I understand the consistency argument (and a good compiler should warn if you assign `container.size()` to an `int`), but calculating the difference between indexes can make sense, and the expression to calculate the difference would be `abs( i1 - i2 )`. Which doesn't give the right result for a `std::size_t`. In the end, in most cases, I'll just use `int` (or a `ptrdiff_t`) -- unless I'm very sure that the index can't overflow (and I often am), I'll use a `checked_cast` in the assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `f` is **non-const**, which means that the non-const member function version is a **better match** than the const member function version since the type of `this` parameter for non-const version is `Foo<int>*` while for the const version it is `const Foo<int>*` and so the latter requires a **qualification conversion** while the former does not and hence a **better match**.

To solve this you can either make `f` const(but then you won't be able to write on it) or use `const_cast` on the non-const `f` as shown below:

```
int main() 
{
     std::vector<int> values(100, 1);

     Foo<int> f{values};  //non-const f
     f(1,1) = 42; //uses write version
     //use read version now as we've used const_cast
     std::cout << const_cast<const Foo<int>&>(f)(1, 1) << '\n'; //use const_cast 
     return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/x8oqqEzhr)

---

With C++17 you can also use [`std::as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) as shown in [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9Gavxdfnf).

Comment: @WeijunZhou Done, added `std::as_const` in the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, operator overload resolution choses the write function because it is called on a non-const object. Overload resolution (generally) doesn't take into account how the results are used. It only considers the types of the parameters.

The usual solution here would be to have the write overload return a proxy; put the actual code of the operators in two different functions (`put` and `get`, for example). The proxy would simply save a pointer to the actual object, and the two arguments. It would have an assignment operator which forwards to the `put` function, and a conversion `operator T() const` which forwards to the `get` function. (When resolving a type conversion operator is one of the rare cases where operator overload resolution takes the target type into account.)

Something like this should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    class Proxy
    {
    public:
        Proxy( Foo* owner, int i, int j )
            :   m_owner( owner )
            ,   m_i( i )
            ,   m_j( j )
        {
        }
        Proxy& operator=( T const& t )
        {
            m_owner->put( m_i, m_j, t );
            return *this;
        }
        operator T const&() const
        {
            return m_owner->get( m_i, m_j );
        }
    private:
        Foo*            m_owner;
        int             m_i;
        int             m_j;
    };

public:
    Foo(std::vector<T> const& values) : vals( values ) {}
    const T &get(int i, int j) const {
        std::cout << "Read" << std::endl;
        return vals[i];
    }
    void put(int i, int j, T const& newValue ) {
        std::cout << "Write" << std::endl;
        vals[i] = newValue;
    } 
    T const& operator()(int i, int j) const {
        std::cout << "Read" << std::endl;
        return vals[i];
    }
    Proxy operator()(int i, int j) {
        return Proxy( this, i, j );
    } 

private:
    std::vector<T> vals;
};

int
main()
{
    std::vector<int> values(100, 1);

    Foo<int> f{values};
    f(1,1) = 42; //here it writes:OK
    std::cout << f(1,1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A bit verbose, but it's a standard idiom, and the `Proxy` class is basically boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was aware of the Proxy pattern, but I don't like that much the fact that I have to construct a Proxy object at every call of `()` operator. Couldn't this be a problem for intensive computing codes? @JamesKanze

Comment: Or do you use the fact that RVO actually holds for the `()` operator? @JamesKanze

Comment: @cnewbie I really count on the fact that the proxy class is entirely inline, and the compiler should optimize it completely away (with a high enough level of optimization -- in builds without optimization, you'll still see it being constructed in the debuger).

Comment: In other words, if you write `f( 1, 2 ) = 42`, the compiler should generate the same code as if you wrote `f.put( 1, 2, 42 )`. This sort of optimization is pretty standard, and has been for the last 30 or 40 years.